# Search and replace a text sequence in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am trying to search and replace a text sequence in a website. The webpage has some text like "#45421" (# followed by 5 digits). I need to replace this with `<a href="http://example.com/45421">#45421</a>`. I tried the below code to do this,

```
var mystring = $('.content').html();
var re = /\b\#d{5}\b/g;
mystring.replace(re, "<a href='http://example.com/'"+re+">"+re+"</a>");
```

But I am unable to get the desired results. I would like to see the text sequence replaced with links as soon as this script is executed. This script is actually injected to that page from a chrome extension. What am I missing here?

Comment: did you mean to use `#\d{5}` instead of `#d{5}`, also note you are not setting the html after doing the replace, and trying to concatenate the wrong thing to your html

Comment: can you post text inside (.content)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use regex capturing groups - put parentheses around the part of the regex you want to capture, and then refer to it in the replacement string as `$1` (and, if you're capturing multiple, the next is `$2` and so on):

```
mystring.replace(/#(\d{5})\b/g, '<a href="http://example.com/$1">#$1</a>');
```

Your regex also has a misplaced escape backslash - the `d` should be escaped, not the `#`

Comment: Not sure it is going to work. `#` is not alphanumeric and hence not taken into account in the word boundary `\b`

Comment: I moved the `\b` to sit between the `#` and `\d` and that I think works: `/#\b(\d{5})\b/g`

Comment: In that case I don't think the first `\b` is actually doing anything, if it's matching a word break between characters that you're already matching anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Dont know if this is what you want**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <style>
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

      <script>
      var mystring = "#45421"
      var re = mystring.match(/#\d{5}/g);
      var re1 = re.toString().replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
      var strReplace =mystring.replace(/#\d{5}/g, "<a href='http://example.com/"+re1+"'"+">"+re+"</a>");

      console.log(strReplace);
      </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```